# How can I dynamically update different fields of a class from inside a method?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I code a C# function to accept a variable number of parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663919/how-can-i-code-a-c-sharp-function-to-accept-a-variable-number-of-parameters)

I have the following class:

```
public class Product : AuditableTable  
{
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public double Location { get; set; }
}
```

What I need is to be able to update fields in the class with the following function.

Parameters:

- ac and pr define the keys and enable me to get an instance of the class.
- fld is the field name of the class to update. It could be "Position", "Quantity" or "Location" or ??
- val is the value. It could be something like "London" or "1.234"

How can I arrange for the field name to be set dynamically without using a case statement to 
check each value of fld and many different setters. Also if there's some way of setting the field
dynamically how do I deal with casting it to the correct object type for that field?

```
    public void Update(string ac, string pr, string fld, string val) 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            vm.Product = _product.Get(ac, pr);
            vm.Product. xxx = fld 
        }
        catch (Exception e) { log(e); }
    }
```

**Update**

Here's the solution proposed by Pieter:

```
public void Update(string ac, string pr, string fld, string val) { 
            try { 
                vm.Product = _product.Get("0000" + ac, pr);
                if (vm.Product != null)
                {
                    var property = vm.Product.GetType().GetProperty(fld);
                    var type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) ?? property.PropertyType;
                    val = Convert.ChangeType(val, type);
                    property.SetValue(vm.Product, val, null); 
                } 
                _product.AddOrUpdate(vm.Product);
            }
            catch (Exception e) { log(e); }
        }
```

Comment: um, hasn't this been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8663926/1106367)?

Comment: What's point in creating duplicates?

Comment: The answer given before doesn't work as the set value tries to set vm instead of vm.Prouct. Looking at this thread I was able to get a little bit further but there is still a problem because none of the answers take datatype conversion into account :-(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use reflection:

```
vm.Product.GetType().GetProperty(field).SetValue(vm.Product, val, null);
```

`SetValue` requires that the value is of the correct type. If this isn't the case, you can convert it with the following:

```
var property = vm.Product.GetType().GetProperty(field);

// Convert.ChangeType does not work with nullable types, so we need
// to get the underlying type.

var type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) ?? property.PropertyType;

object convertedValue = Convert.ChangeType(val, type);

property.SetValue(vm.Product, convertedValue, null);
```

This automatically converts `val` to the type of the property before assigning it.

Note however that both using reflection and `Convert.ChangeType` are horribly slow. If you do this a lot, you should have a look at [`DynamicMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Pieter. This was an answer I had seen before but I had a problem getting it to work. I'll check it again. Maybe I made a mistake.

Comment: It can be tricky to get reflection to work. If you encounter specific issues, just comment them here.

Comment: thanks for the answer. It almost works. But there's a problem here: [System.ArgumentException] = {"Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Double]'."}    val is always a string but the properties could be different. Here the property location is a double so when I try to update with a string I get this error.

Comment: I've updated the answer with this requirement.

Comment: looks good but I get a compile error on the line val = Convert.ChangeType(val, type); ---- Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 2):

Reflection is what you can use.

```
Type myType = Vm.Product.GetType();
PropertyInfo pinfo = myType.GetProperty(fld);
//get property type
Type convertType = pinfo.PropertyType;
//convert it to the required type before setting the property value
var newValue = Convert.ChangeType(val, convertType);

// Use the SetValue method to change the caption.
pinfo.SetValue(vm.Product, newValue , null);
```

The only thing that you have to keep in mind that if the property is double, then the string that is being passed should be such that it could be converted to double, other wise you would have a runtime exception

more info here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/axt1ctd9.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it only works if the datatypes are the same. Still needs some way to convert datatypes. Some kind of cast but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: That can be done also. See my edited code

Answer (score 1):

Use Reflection in c#

```
    public void Update(string ac, string pr, string fld, string val) { 
    try 
       { 
           vm.Product = _product.Get(ac, pr);
           if( vm.Product != null)
             {
                Type type =  vm.Product.GetType();
                PropertyInfo pIn = type.GetProperty(fld);
                if(pIn != null)
                     pIn.SetValue(vm.Product, val, null);

             }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { log(e); }
     }
```

Comment: Hello. See my comments above. Still a problem as it only works if the datatypes of val and the property match.